# App Engine Connected Android : can't make sample project work properly

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-c2dm

I want to make an App Engine connected Android app, and I'm beginning with google's tutorial available here :
http://code.google.com/intl/fr/eclipse/docs/appeng_android_create_project.html

I did exactly as they did (registered into C2DM service, installed plugins, signed on in eclipse with my google acc, etc...), but when I launch the sample app (with "Debug as" > "Local App Engine connected Android Application") and I click on the button "say hello", I get the message "Failure: Connection to http://127.0.1.1:8888 refused.

I deployed Server side package on GAE, removed file debugging_prefs.properties, and ran it on my phone, it worked. But no way to make it work in test environment ....

I have eclipse 3.7 Indigo, App Engine plugin 1.6.1, and GWT 2.4.0, on Ubuntu 10.04.

Any idea ? Thanks for help.

edit : just installed eclipse and plugins in a Windows XP VM... worked on the first try ... But still not in my Ubuntu :(

edit 2 : freshly installed ubuntu 11.10 in an other VM. Same error as in my 10.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work using the answer I received [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/issues/detail?id=46). I've add this line in `getDebugUrl` in util class

```
s = "url=http://192.168.1.50:8888";
```

with `192.168.1.50` being my Ubuntu VM IP address