# App Engine connected android project connection error

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I've started out with the App Engine. Created the App Engine connected Android project.

I'm running it locally,on the AVD emulator 2.3.3. I have my Google account registered in the phone.
I've also registered at the C2DM service.

But when i press the "say hello" button,i get an ClassNotFoundexception.

Also,on the http://127.0.0.1:8888/AppIdeas2.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 ,if i press the "SAY HELLO" button i get an SERVER ERROR 500 error . and if i try to send a ping to the phone i get an SERVER ERROR 500 error.
I've searched around,but can't seem to figure it out.

I wanted to attach screenshots , but haven't got the reputation for it yet..

Help would be much appreciated.

Eclipse code:

אפר 24, 2012 10:25:59 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin

אפר 24, 2012 11:05:17 AM com.google.appengine.api.search.dev.LuceneDirectoryMap$FileBased 
SEVERE: File base storage: root directory doesn't exist

אפר 24, 2012 11:05:17 AM com.google.appengine.api.search.dev.LocalSearchService init
INFO: search initialized

אפר 24, 2012 11:05:17 AM com.google.appengine.api.search.dev.LocalSearchService start
INFO: search started

אפר 24, 2012 11:21:14 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
WARNING: No file found for: /_ah/admin/ not showing phone

Comment: What platform are you using? There are several problems it seems. Linux: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872521/app-engine-connected-android-cant-make-sample-project-work-properly - JDK7: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088810/app-engine-connected-android-project-c2dm-connection-error are just a few I found using Google.

Answer (score 0):

think of your emulator as a different machine, so it wouldn consider  http://127.0.0.1:8888 it's own local host, not your app engine dev server. Instead, run app engine using a network IP and call that from the emulator.