# App Engine Connected Android : failure connection refused

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I've been following these instructions https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appeng_android_create_project to setup an app engine connected android project.

I have gwt 2.4, android sdk 18, app engine plugin 1.6.6, eclipse indigo, and windows 7. I have also signed up for a c2dm account.  I'm attempting to run the project on my galaxy nexus running android 4 because I can't seem to add an account to the emulator in order to "connect to the cloud".

When I click, "Say Hello" I eventually get the error message:

```
Failure: Connection to http://192.168.2.2:8888 refused
```

192.168.2.2 actually IS my ip address according to ipconfig.

I am aware of this question [App Engine Connected Android : can't make sample project work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872521/app-engine-connected-android-cant-make-sample-project-work-properly) however his error shows a failure to connect to 127.0.1.1 while mine shows my actual IP address. Nevertheless, I have attempted his solution with both my local and public ip address but always get the same error, just with a different ip address.

Can anyone please help?

Edit:

After Peter pointed out my ip address problem, I decided to deploy to app engine real quick to see if it works there.  I successfully deployed and then ran the android part on my phone.  After clicking force close, the app says, "Connecting..." for a very long time and then force closes. In logcat I get the error message:

```
06-01 18:05:14.678: E/AndroidRuntime(11328): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-01 18:05:14.678: E/AndroidRuntime(11328): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.testprojectfourteen.UPDATE_UI flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.testprojectfourteen.TestProjectFourteenActivity$1@41826430
06-01 18:05:14.678: E/AndroidRuntime(11328):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:737)
06-01 18:05:14.678: E/AndroidRuntime(11328):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-01 18:05:14.678: E/AndroidRuntime(11328):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-01 18:05:14.678: E/AndroidRuntime(11328):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-01 18:05:14.678: E/AndroidRuntime(11328):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
06-01 18:05:14.678: E/AndroidRuntime(11328):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-01 18:05:14.678: E/AndroidRuntime(11328):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-01 18:05:14.678: E/AndroidRuntime(11328):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-01 18:05:14.678: E/AndroidRuntime(11328):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-01 18:05:14.678: E/AndroidRuntime(11328):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-01 18:05:14.678: E/AndroidRuntime(11328): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-01 18:05:14.678: E/AndroidRuntime(11328):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:195)
06-01 18:05:14.678: E/AndroidRuntime(11328):    at com.testprojectfourteen.Util.generateNotification(Util.java:119)
06-01 18:05:14.678: E/AndroidRuntime(11328):    at com.testprojectfourteen.TestProjectFourteenActivity$1.onReceive(TestProjectFourteenActivity.java:82)
06-01 18:05:14.678: E/AndroidRuntime(11328):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:728)
06-01 18:05:14.678: E/AndroidRuntime(11328):    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Put four spaces at the beginning of the line to make text look like code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `192.168.2.2` is a [private IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) and is not visible on the internet. C2DM is a google-run public service which tries to connect to your private IP, but it can not reach it, hence the error.

The workaround is to find out the [internet-visible IP](http://www.whatismyip.com/) of you router and set up [port-forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) on it (this is router dependent).

Comment: THANK YOU! That makes a lot of sense. I'm going to setup port-forwarding asap. For now I thought it might be easier to just deploy to app engine and see if it works there. I deployed with no problems but then got the error in logcat that I just put in my question. I don't guess you know what that one means do you? :) :)

Comment: Did you register for C2DM? http://how2code.wordpress.com/2011/11/23/your-first-connect-to-the-cloud-error/

Comment: Yes I did. I registered my personal gmail account. That is also the account I entered when creating the new app engine connected project.

However, when I registered it asked me for a package name. I gave it a package name for a different app. Do I need to reregister and give it the package name of this app?

Comment: Also, my person gmail account (that I registered for c2dm) is also the one stored in my phone. That's the one I click when it says, "Connect to the cloud". Is that ok?

Comment: Ah, your link answered that question :)

Edit: Actually I think that only applies to non-gmail...

Comment: http://how2code.wordpress.com/2011/11/24/fatal-exception-intentservice-due-to-nullpointerexception-on-pendingintent-getactivity/

Comment: Yay! That link fixed the error I was getting in logcat! Thank you! However, now my app is back to saying "Failure: Connection to http://192.168.2.2:8888 refused" even though I deployed to app engine.  I'm selecting Run as->Android application. Why would it be trying to use my ip address?

Comment: Search your codebase, client and server, for `192.168.2.2:8888`

Comment: I found the line "url=http://192.168.2.2:8888" in debugging_prefs.prop.  I changed the ip address in that file and it changed the ip address I got in the error message, so the IP address is definitely coming from debugging_prefs.prop.  Why is it using the debugging url when I'm not debugging?

Comment: IT WORKS!!!! I created a new app with all lowercase letters.  I don't know if it was the new app or the lowercase letters than did it, but it works now! YAYAYAY! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!

Comment: Do you know under what circumstances I would need to run the validation tool described here http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryInterfaceValidation